# How to reuse different types from one component to one component in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
interface FetchData {
  name: string;
  src: string;
  id: string;
  price: number;
}
interface FetchData2 {
  title: string;
  src: string;
  _id:string
  item_price: number;
}

const Item = ({ item }: FetchData | FetchData2) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <p>{item.name || item.title}</p>  //I can't figure out the type.
      <img src={item.src}/>
      <p>{item.price || item.item_price}</p> //I can't figure out the type.
    </li>
  )
};

const List = ({ type }: { type: 'foo' | 'bar' }) => {
  const fetchData = axios.get<FetchData[]>('blablabla');
  const fetchData2 = axios.get<FetchData2[]>('blablabla');
  return type === 'foo'
    ? fetchData.map((item) => <Item key={item.id} item={item} />)
    : fetchData2.map((item) => <Item key={item._id} item={item} />);
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <List type="foo" />
      <List type="bar" />
    </ul>
  );
}
```

This code uses 'TypeScript' in 'React'.
The code below obtains data through two 'fetch'.
The return value of fetch is slightly different, but I thought I could reduce the amount of code if I reuse it, so I tried reusing it.
A type issue occurs.
I wrote down the type in the 'Item' component below, so only the type 'src' is caught.
I want to use the right type of code to reduce the amount of code.
How shall I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.** [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html?#discriminated-unions).

E.g.

```
import React from 'react';

interface FetchData {
    kind: 'a';
    name: string;
    src: string;
    id: string;
    price: number;
}
interface FetchData2 {
    kind: 'b';
    title: string;
    src: string;
    _id: string;
    item_price: number;
}

function Item({ item }: { item: FetchData | FetchData2 }) {
    return (
        <li>
            <p>{item.kind === 'a' ? item.name : item.title}</p>
            <img src={item.src} />
            <p>{item.kind === 'a' ? item.price : item.item_price}</p>
        </li>
    );
}

function List({ type }: { type: 'foo' | 'bar' }) {
    const fetchData: FetchData[] = [];
    const fetchData2: FetchData2[] = [];
    return (
        <>
            {type === 'foo'
                ? fetchData.map((item) => (
                        <Item
                            key={item.id}
                            item={item}
                        />
                  ))
                : fetchData2.map((item) => (
                        <Item
                            key={item._id}
                            item={item}
                        />
                  ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <List type='foo' />
            <List type='bar' />
        </ul>
    );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AxJGNACwBEUYKOAG8qccXADWdACYAuAijJiJtFCCQKAzjCh0A5hUoS4WqGm26DRk8HmmrtQyvFg9aTXFoBXEACNGIwBfGnpGZg92Th5+QQAmERcpWQV8P2VjCRhgGAAbTx09JxsJMwsHIudM8QB9O0tKkvEcpBAat2APBR9-QKoQ6kpMb1oMYAhaOABJBhAACmE4FrwghUXlhQ4uPgEhAB8o7diUBKCASkTquCIYbyhJuaSTAB5c4AA+J5MJZ7B34WWADppLQZHAALyQxT4OAAfiWs0Bag0cAUQOyeSQQWeAHo-l9vnBnqB9KZzOCAYiykE4DjPldCeJfv8gSCwZDwdC4QjWoCOpE0Yjlu13FjcfiGT8cW96SYzsEqFRhqNshM4AAZYA6BZwGAATzArFWIl1Bs8+EwEAgMIOaRQUBh50uJjQEx0cEw0R2gk2XuOAG0ALoQuBBppwV20d2eo67OK+2PxIMhsNJG53B4EomyxkmYT6w0QqEWq34LO5+ExmK7QEgFBgOZzZYXcHvOCPSW5wnPGatctdwmSJB6ilAuwDAeTiTLUezCdTxl0-uEs5nZffBRV70nWv1xvNiFtjsLxk92brqdDkeU3l1GTzk+5mc3kAPx-iJedrurt8vT9yhVBiQAAPSBYDgGQkGYbxciwEYxjVABBMAGwuUQrnTe52yzZ4YJzAdnk1d0CyQcES2tWl8K7QitXgEiyL8e0YX-U8cTwpJ5X6KggA)

**Option 2. Generic Components**

```
import React from 'react';

interface FetchData {
    name: string;
    src: string;
    id: string;
    price: number;
}
interface FetchData2 {
    title: string;
    src: string;
    _id: string;
    item_price: number;
}

function Item<T extends { src: string }>({
    item,
    title,
    price,
}: {
    item: T;
    title: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
    price: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <li>
            <p>{title(item)}</p>
            <img src={item.src} />
            <p>{price(item)}</p>
        </li>
    );
}

function List({ type }: { type: 'foo' | 'bar' }) {
    const fetchData: FetchData[] = [];
    const fetchData2: FetchData2[] = [];
    return (
        <>
            {type === 'foo'
                ? fetchData.map((item) => (
                        <Item
                            key={item.id}
                            item={item}
                            title={(i) => i.name}
                            price={(i) => i.price}
                        />
                  ))
                : fetchData2.map((item) => (
                        <Item
                            key={item._id}
                            item={item}
                            title={(i) => i.title}
                            price={(i) => i.item_price}
                        />
                  ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <List type='foo' />
            <List type='bar' />
        </ul>
    );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AxJGNACwBEUYKOAG8qccXFooQSAFxwAzjCh0A5hUoTFUNPKUra6sROAATPcrUatYFWjmSAriABGjDQF8a9Rs3vtOHn5BACYRY3EYYBgAGwd9KwjtXUVLQ2sJAH0zCwMjTRMGEEzbYHt5Wmc3KE8qKkxHWgxgCFo4AEkigB4AFTgkAA8GWlMFEWTctTgPAD4ACmE4aKQQABo4KNikddL-D3lF5ZB5HtIN6Lj5OaOTgEo4AF4ZxGIYADpkdBgAOQhTJDOuwc1yKd0ez0+GA+r1+-2m91EBXERBgjigbTmSS0XRiwBmWK0Ei6YBmwk2cRBK1uHi6AHoSQTCXAuqBVMkHsIjm8FDoPHBafikUyiSThEDKSBqXSGULsbTcYKtLdatRKA0mlFWnAADLAJQLDYATzArH24xgxoc+EwEAg+DgAB8CC4UFB7R4EUk0K0lHBMIE+AIUPIOFxA4IANoAXUecGjGXE3tovv9YeCKBCIYD6ZC0dj8aSKLRGMZzMVwq0ZMtjweDwINrtpYrAH4-dmg28QCgwHMJfcnnBMbKK8Kup0Vk2R0yANZIQ0crlmLzDqcVo4LorL1fb85bBfgpZvKQyLc7qdA-cD4BvIGns9aAWTpm3W5PwnyVNBIMhTvd3tHftniHe9CTHIo323Wd505Io3myUw7xAwl1xglZEKQiRySQS9nmvLD0IwuAL05A9ryOEo7CQAiz0fFcRxfajmVopUVSoQZIFgOB-mYRwYiwRpmi1ABBMAe09IUi3RQdSy6XjyynLpdV9C0TQea1bXtZjV0UvV4BU7D8BdN1+Xk0DaTkpJlSoZcgA)